# Adding blank pages when generating multiple copies of a document

Tags: automation, datatool, blank-page

I'm generating multiple copies (right now, 2, but a general solution would be nice) of a letter with minor variations using datatool. I just realised that if I'm printing it double-sided. and if the number of pages is odd, then the last page of the first letter is back to back with the first page of the second letter. Is there a good way to add an extra blank page as necessary. Do I need to add an MWE for this?

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but I only want that if the number of pages is odd. Is there some way of determining that programmatically?

Comment: I think it'll do what you want - http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_103.html It'll make the next page on the "right-hand" side.

Comment: Presumably you want a new page anyway for the start of a letter? so just use `\cleardoublepage` just as `\cleardoublepage` at the start of a chapter only throws a blank page if the previous chapter had an odd number of pages

Comment: I do this with `textmerg` and `\cleardoublepage` works fine. Make sure the `twoside` option is active, of course. (But if you are printing double-sided, you'll be using this anyway.)